# Result of merge in QGIS is image that doesn't contains all the merged raster

Tags: qgis, gdal, merge, gdal-merge

I'm trying to merge ~10 rasters that I have on qgis. Each raster has 2 bands.**The rasters overlap each other, and their no-data value is -9999.**

This is how all the rasters look like before merging (the black and white frame disappear when I zoom in) :

[image]

For example,  this is how one raster looks like:
[image]

I am trying to use gdal tool to merge them as following:
[image]

The gdal command:

```
gdal_merge.bat -n -9999.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=NONE -co BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED -o C:/Users/this/is/path/OUTPUT.tif --optfile C:/Users/USER/AppData/this/is/path/mergeInputFiles.txt
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

**as you can see, it has missing rasters.

My question is what could be the reasons for this error? and how can I overcome it?**
(similar error occurs to me also when I try it with rasterio, but couldn't find any problem with the rasters).

Comment: Have a try by assigning nodata into output. For my mind the other merging tool "Build virtual raster" (actually this GDAL tool https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) is better for almost any use case.

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Also, in your gdal command the no data value is set to -10004.0, not -9999 as shown in your qgis advanced parameters.